# mysql union Minus Syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

TBL frequents Schema - drinker VARCHAR(50) PK, bar VARCHAR(50) PK

Bars which are frequented by John or Rebecca but not by both of them

my query is :

((select bar from frequents where drinker='john') union (select bar from frequents where drinker='Rebecca') )

minus

(select f1.bar from frequents f1, frequents f2 where f1.bar=f2.bar and f1.drinker='john' and f2.drinker='rebecca')

but the minus keeps giving me a syntax error saying "minus is not valid at this position expecting eof ;" but i can not figure out how to fix it. I have added the ; different places to see if it works but i am not getting an answer. I know all of my subqueries are returning the correct values i just need to get the minus operator to work.

thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not support MINUS operator. See: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support MINUS operator. However, you can use the MySQL join to simulate it. The strategy is to LEFT JOIN all rows and keep the ones that the second join is NULL, because it mean that doen't mach (MINUS).

In you example:

```
SELECT table1.bar 
    FROM ((select bar from frequents where drinker='john') UNION (select bar from frequents where drinker='Rebecca')) table1 
    LEFT JOIN (select f1.bar from frequents f1, frequents f2 where f1.bar=f2.bar and f1.drinker='john' and f2.drinker='rebecca') table2 ON (table1.bar = table2.bar) 
    WHERE table2.bar IS NULL;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although your one table of drinker and bar is ok, you might want to look into normalizing data before things get to far...  Having a master table of all bars, another of all people, and a third that just holds the IDs of each bar and person who attends.

Having said that, I would write the query doing self-join to the table in question on each name but only where both are not null.

```
select
      AllBars.Bar
   from
      ( select distinct bar 
           from frequents  ) AllBars

         LEFT JOIN ( select distinct bar 
                       from frequents  
                       where drinker = 'john' ) JohnsBars
            on AllBars.bar = JohnsBars.bar

         LEFT JOIN ( select distinct bar 
                       from frequents 
                       where drinker = 'Rebecca' ) RebeccasBars
            on AllBars.bar = RebeccasBars.bar
   where
            ( JohnsBars.bar IS NOT NULL
         OR RebeccasBars.bar IS NOT NULL )
      AND NOT ( JohnsBars.bar = RebeccasBars.Bar )
```

So the first part of the OR in the where makes sure qualifies that at least ONE of them go to the bar.  The AND portion makes sure they don't go to the SAME bar together.